# User suddenly getting ORA-01013 on updates when they hadn't before

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not a DBA, just a 'regular' user.

I've got a script that I run weekly against both our development and production server which 'upserts' values into a table not directly owned by me.

Last week I started receiving ORA-01031 errors whenever I attempted to run this script on the development server but not on the production server.

As far as I know, there have been no system level changes.

On further investigation this seemed to only impact me. Other users were able to run the scripts without issue on either system.

Addtionally this occurs to any update/insert I attempt regardless of table.

Our DBA dropped and recreated my account, which didn't seem to impact anything. What other items should we be checking?

Comment: _"As far as I know, there have been no system level changes."_, well it looks like your permissions have been revoked or you're now running the code against views you didn't previously have permissions to access...

Comment: Title say ORA-01013, body of question says ORA-01031.  Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some stuff to try:

- Have the other users run the exact script you are trying to run and see if they get the error.
- Carefully compare your script(s) against the script(s) that are working.  Are there ANY differences?  It could be something small like leaving out the schema name.
- Check with the DBAs to see if ANY new database changes went in recently.  It could be due to a new schema, new privileges, new synonyms, new policies, etc.

Comment: Turns out it was the last one. They were doing security cleanup and forgot a particular change they made.